# HTML Email size doesn't change on iphone

Tags: ios, html-email

For some reason on iPhone my font-size is still tiny.  I've got a responsive template that works well, but for some reason the font size seems to stay at around 12px.  I know there's some rule that iPhone will resize fonts if they are too small, but I want to make it larger.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is causing that issue?

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by having `min-width:600px;` on my tables.  I had done this to try and force Gmail app to behave.  This is not a viable solution for me anymore.

Guess I'll try these: https://css-tricks.com/override-gmail-mobile-optimized-email/

Comment: I have found that Gmail on iPhone is bar far the worst for supporting any kind of hack to force responsive design.

Comment: Gmail doesn't support media queries, so for that reason you're right.  Using the above link I implemented:

`<div style="display: none; white-space: nowrap; line-height: 0; color: #ffffff;">
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
</div>`

That worked for me to keep the original dimensions and resolve my issues.  It's not responsive, but it's not half and half either which was far worse